# Spermatozoa and sperms

Tags: sexual-reproduction

Does  spermatozoa and sperm have different meaning?If they are same why do wikipedia have 2webpages ? But most websites mention them as the same thing.I am confused .Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In broad way we call it sperm but the motile sperm is precisely called spermatozoon and plural form of spermatozoon is spermatozoa. A non motile male gamete is sperm but not spermatozoon but there is a term for that too its spermatium.

Comment: Not just in humans most animals have sperm, in fact non-motile sperm cells would be the basal condition.